# eslint does not allow 4 spaces for indent

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I have installed eslint and eslint-plugin-vue for my project.
When I load the project in the browser, I get the following warning in the console:

> http://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent        Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4
>     src\_nav.js:2:1

This is my _nav.js:

```
export default {
    items: [{  /*this is line 2 - indented with 4 spaces*/
```

I have tried to tell lint that I want to use 4 spaces, but I still get the warning. I have the same problem with .vue files.

This is my .eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    parserOptions: {
        parser: 'babel-eslint'
    },
    env: {
        browser: true,
    },
    extends: [
        // https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue#priority-a-essential-error-prevention
        // consider switching to `plugin:vue/strongly-recommended` or `plugin:vue/recommended` for stricter rules.
        'plugin:vue/essential',
        // https://github.com/standard/standard/blob/master/docs/RULES-en.md
        'standard'
    ],
    // required to lint *.vue files
    plugins: [
        'vue'
    ],
    // add your custom rules here
    rules: {
        // allow async-await
        'generator-star-spacing': 'off',
        // allow debugger during development
        'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
        "indent": ["error", 4],
        "vue/html-indent": ["error", 4],
        "vue/script-indent": ["error", 4],
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure eslint loads the configuration file? It should be called .eslintrc.js, not .eslintrs.js

Comment: Yes, filename is correct (I just had a typo in the question). How can I test if config is loaded from this file?

Comment: Add a deliberate syntax error and see if eslint halts.

Comment: No, it doesn't - this is good hint - I need to look into my webpack configuration

Comment: Suddenly it works with 4 blanks - and ignores it if I switch back to 2 spaces - I think there's some caching involved.

Comment: For other users: my solution is to remove this mega-mega buggy plugin (I could care my code indentation without "mega errors") `npm remove @vue/cli-plugin-eslint `